# Can no longer "switch user" in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vpn, login

I Installed RSA SecurID and Cisco VPN client for Windows 7 (software from [this page](http://isdp.nih.gov/isdp/version.action?prodid=140)). Since then the switch user button (from the switch user/log off/lock interface) has been greyed out. Is there a quick way to restore it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you are referring to is called "Fast User Switch." It allows you to switch user accounts without logging off the current one.

You can turn it back on under `gpedit.msc`.

Computer Configuration/Admin/System/Logon