# LocalPolicy doesn't enable switch user in Windows 7 Pro

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, fast-user-switching

I don't have `Switch User` item in my start menu. Checking group policy as in [Can no longer "switch user" in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/339209/can-no-longer-switch-user-in-windows-7) didn't help as all policied are not defined. `Resulting policy` is not defined either.

How can I enable user switch?

Here is some extra info:

When I run `tsdiscon` I get to user selection screen, but when I try to login it wants to log off the other user, so I cannot have 2 users logged on.

I also miss `Remote Desktop` settings in control panel and cannot enable the remote desktop access.

I have 2 monitors which is supported whenever FUS is supported so OS edition is not the problem.

Comment: I use remote desktop all the time.  Can you not use: Control Panel\System and Security\System?

Comment: When I go to `Control Panel\System and Security\System\Remote Settings\Remote` I don't see `Remote Desktop` control group, only `Remote Assistance`

Comment: Sounds like a Group Policy restriction to me.